# Second monitor turns automatically on and the device input sound comes from speakers after Windows locked

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a desktop PC running Windows 11 with newest updates and drivers for the GPU (RX 6800XT) and chipset (AM4). After I lock my PC with WIN + L it takes around a minute for the main and secondary display to go to sleep. After a minute my secondary monitor turns on, stays black, the Windows device input sound comes from speakers and it goes back to sleep again. Then again a minute later this cycle continues.

Besides updates I have tried to change the displayport cable and refresh rate of the monitor to no avail.

Comment: No idea about any possible answer or suggestion. Just commenting to let you know AM4 is the socket (for AMD CPUs), not the chipset.

Comment: Yes the AM4 is also the socket but the chipset drivers are divided under the sockets. AM4 has B550 (what I got) and X570 and AM5 B650 and X670 for example.

Comment: Yes, the sockets determine what generations and types of CPUs fit there and consequently what chipsets work with any given CPU. Still, **sockets aren't chipsets**.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode? Try also to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Been there, done that, same issue.  I replaced the Monitor and moved on. The manufacturer of the first monitor could not fix the issue.

Comment: In Safe Mode the computer only recognizes the main display. Tried  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and sfc /scannow but didn't work. Also tried removing both monitors from device manager but that didn't resolve the issue either. Thanks for the tip though. The tool found some corrupted files and repaired them.

Comment: The patching by SFC is not perfect, I use it more as an indication that Windows is screwed, not as a fix. To be sure, I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as doing a Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing the cable from DP to HDMI